# How do i construct $C^\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, derivatives

I'm trying to define $C^\infty$ rigorously and i have a trouble with this. Mathematical Induction should be used, but i dunno where to apply this. I'm going to illustrate what i tried below:

Before I start, to make it clear, I used the notation $C^n$ to mean the set of $n$-times differentiable functions.(Not continuously differentiable)

Let $S$ be a subset of $\mathbb{K}$ such that $\forall x\in S, x$ is a limit point of $S\setminus \{x\}$. (So that *derivative* of a given function on this domain makes sense)

Let $(V,\|\cdot\|)$ be a normed space over $\mathbb{K}$.

Now, define $C^1(S)\triangleq \{f\in V^S : f \text{ is differentiable }\}$

Then, let $D:C^1(S)\rightarrow V^S:f\mapsto f'$ be a differentiation operator.

Then, one can define $C^2(S)$ as $\{f\in C^1(S) : D(f) \in C^1(S)\}$.

Now, we can show that $\forall f\in C^2(S), f$ is twice-differentiable, so that $D^2(f)$ makes sense for function in $C^2(f)$.

In this manner, we can construct $C^3(S)$ as the set $\{f\in C^2(S): D(f) \in C^1(S)\}$.

But i dunno how to construct a function to apply the Mathematical Induction to define $C^n(S)$ for all $n\in \mathbb{Z}^+$.

Please someone help me :) Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Pedro Yes, I know that, but I'm asking how to construct $C^n$ for all $n$

Comment: To make my point clear, if a finite number $m$ is given, there is no problem with constructing $C^n$ for all $n≦m$. However, to construct all $C^n$, one must pass through Induction, but I dunno how to apply mathematical induction to construct all $C^n$'s

Comment: Also, it would be really great to know if there is a widely-using notation for the set of all $n$-times differentiable functions. (I know that $C^n$ does not mean the set of *just* $n$-times differentiable functions :)

Comment: You can define the space of infinitely differentiable functions to be the functions for which any derivative is continuous, ergo are elements of $C^n$ for all $n$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very simple to define $C^\infty$, given that you know how to define $C^n(S)$, and you should be familiar with this construction for many situations.

$$C^{\infty}(S) := \bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}C^n(S)$$

In plain English, "something is infinitely differentiable if it is differentiable n times for any n."

As for $C^n$, you already have

> Then, one can define C2(S) as {f∈C1(S):D(f)∈C1(S)}.

Or: $$C^{n+1}(S) := \{f \in C^n(S) : D(f) \in C^n(S)\}$$

This is basically what you had.

Mathematicians will generally accept this as a rigorous definition, but you are correct that this is an inductive definition that somehow doesn't use induction. In fact it uses the [recursion theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/907357/the-recursion-theorem-set-theory) which permits these definitions to be rigorous. The reason such a theorem is necessary is that while it's fine to prove a property $P$ inductively, but "is defined" is not a property in any useful sense: *what* is defined?

I've sketched a proof for the special case of the factorial function. It may be instructive in that it shows where the "inductive definition" went, in the part you got stuck or weren't comfortable handwaving.

What I will actually do is show that it's possible to define factorial on the sets $S_n := \{k \in \mathbb N : k \leq n\}$, by induction, and that furthermore since these functions will agree on their domains, one can define $n!$ as the factorial function on $S_n$ at $n$.

Let's say a function $f$ on a fixed $S_n$ has the factorial property if $f(0) = 1$ and $\forall n > 0$, $f(n) = nf(n-1)$. We prove each $S_n$ has a unique function $f_n$ with the factorial property by induction, and that furthermore if $m < n$ that $f_n|_{S_m} = f_m$, from which it follows that $F(n) := f_n(n)$ is the unique factorial function. The proof sketch is as follows:

1. Prove that $S_0$ has a unique factorial function.
2. Prove that $S_{n+1}$ has a unique factorial function, by using the unique factorial function $f_n$ elicited by the inductive hypotheses.
3. Prove that they agree.
4. Prove that the globally constructed $F$ above has the factorial property.
5. Prove by induction (easy induction with no $S_n$ involved) that if two functions have the factorial property on $\mathbb N$ that they are equal.

From (5) it follows that $F$ is the unique factorial function on $\mathbb N$.

Comment: It is not an *inductive* definition. We refer to definitions of these kind as recursive, and there is a *recursion theorem* that formalizes them. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/907357/462) for a version that suffices for the case at hand.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo thanks, added to my answer. I think it's instructive enough to include the proof for factorial, since it shows where the induction "went". I assume this proof lifts to a proof of the recursion theorem.

Comment: Yes, other than the general case being notationally more cumbersome, all the ideas needed in its proof are already in the case you presented.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your question correctly, but if one wants to define $C^n$ by induction, I would proceed as follows:

- (induction basis) Define $C^1(S):=\{f\in V^S\ | f\ $is differentiable$\}$ as you did.
- (induction hypothesis) Assume that we have already defined $C^n$ for a fixed $n\in\mathbb N$.
- (induction step) Let $D$ be the differential operator as defined in the question. By the induction hypothesis, $C^n$ is well defined. We then define
  $$
  C^{n+1}(S):=\{f\in C^n(S)\ |\ D(f)\in C^n(S)\}.
  $$
  This should do the job. Moreover, $C^\infty(S)$ can be defined via $C^\infty(S):=\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}C^n(S)$.

Comment: I'm afraid to say that you are wrong. Take n=3. By your construction, $C^3=\{f\in C^2:D(f)\in C^1\} = C^2$

Comment: Yeah you are right. I tried to correct the answer.